# How to use preventBack() to remove a div when pressing back?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code forwards when hitting back:

```
    <script type = "text/javascript" >
    function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
    setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
    window.onunload=function(){null};
    </script>
```

This code removes div after a given time:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#box').remove();
    }, 5000);
    </script>
```

I want to combine both to make it work! Please help me, when visitor comes and clicks on pop up and goes to next page if they come back by using swipe back or back button the div removes. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.onbeforeunload` predefined function which help you to get solution

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
$('#box').remove();
 };
```

Comment: Pls provide the working example on plunkar/jsfiddle so that i can help you as per your need..